# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class View

Tags: java, exception, javafx, runtime

I am trying to instantiate an object of type `Application` outside of where I wrote my static main method and I am getting this exception.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new View(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;

public class View extends Application {
    public View(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class View
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2/1867083167.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$158(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$46/1861073381.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1540794519.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1604144171.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/718368050.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/1823101961.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:162)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:143)
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:252)
    at View.<init>(View.java:33)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Please share exception stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to do, but invoking `launch(args)` in your constructor looks wrong. From javadocs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-):

> The launch method does not return until the application has exited, either via a call to Platform.exit or all of the application windows have been closed.

Even if it worked, it would hang in your constructor. If you need to do it outside `main()` method, use some static instantiator.